# to check whether the search element isn't available in DB

Tags: java, phpmyadmin

I'm using **phpmy admin** and I need to Display "Not Found" message in case searching element is not found in the DB.
Used code is here.

```
Connection c = DBconnect.connect();
Statement s = c.createStatement();
String e = txtempId.getText();
 ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM nonacademic WHERE empId='" +e+ "'");
```

I used this method to search empId ,if empId is not available in db I need to display a message.Please give me a solution how to detect, if empId is not available in DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use if statement like this

```
Connection c = DBconnect.connect();
Statement s = c.createStatement();
String e = txtempId.getText();
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM nonacademic WHERE empId='" +e+ "'");
if(rs.next())
{
     do
     {
         // If there is data, then process it
     }
     while(rs.next());
}
else
    System.out.println("Not Found");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 if (rs != null)
{
  out.println("result set has got something");
  while (rs.next())
  { 
    //I am processing result set now
  }
}
else
{
  out.println("Not Found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added parse of text to integer, assuming `empId` is an integer.

```
int empId = Integer.parseInt(txtempId.getText());
try (Connection c = DBconnect.connect()) {
    String sql = "SELECT *" +
                  " FROM nonacademic" +
                 " WHERE empId = ?";
    try (Statement s = c.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        s.setInt(1, empId);
        try (ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery()) {
            if (! rs.next()) {
                // not found
            } else {
                // found, call rs.getXxx(...) to get values
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the basic simple **if & else statement**. If the **ResultSet** is "null" or it doesn't contain any record display the Message otherwise read data & display.

```
Connection c = DBconnect.connect();
Statement s = c.createStatement();
String e = txtempId.getText();
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM nonacademic WHERE empId='" +e+ "'");
if(rs.next())
         // record found do the processing
else
    System.out.println("Not Found");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  String e = txtempId.getText();
  String sql="select *from nonacademic where empId='"+ e+"' ";
   try {
    boolean status=DatabaseConnection.checkValue(sql);
     if (status) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
          "This id is available");    

          } else {

          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
          "Not found");
                      }
         } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

This method return check whether the search element is exist or not

```
   public static boolean checkValue(String sql) throws Exception {
    boolean b = false;
    ResultSet rst = null;
    Statement st = getStatement();
    rst = st.executeQuery(sql);
    if (rst.next()) {
        b = true;
    }
    return b;
}
```